# INotifyPropertyChanged and his null event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to update my label on WPF form with name "CurrentMoney";
I wrote class Money which was implemented from "INotifyPropertyChanged".

UPD: I'm changed to MVVM pattern with create ViewModelBase class.
Still have "PropertyChaged" null. How can fix it and why it happend?

Money.cs

```
    public class Money : ViewModelBase {
    private double currentMoney;

    public double CurrentMoney {
        get => currentMoney;
        set {
            currentMoney = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentMoney");
        }
    }

    public Money() => currentMoney = 10000;

    public int addMoney(double count) {
        CurrentMoney += count;
        return 1;
    }       
    public int subMoney(double count) {
        CurrentMoney -= count;
        if (currentMoney < 0)
            return 100;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

MainWindow.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {

    public Money currentMoney;

    public MainWindow ( ) {
        InitializeComponent();
        currentMoney = new Money();
        CurrentMoney.DataContext = currentMoney;
    }

    private void Initialize() {
        CurrentMoney.Content = "Current money: " + currentMoney.CurrentMoney;
        CurrentPollution.Content = CurrentPollution.Content.ToString() + Pollution.CurrentPollution;
        Facktories.Content = Facktories.Content.ToString() + FactoriesList.Quantity;
        FactoriesPollution.Content = FactoriesPollution.Content.ToString() + FactoriesList.FullPolution;
    }

    private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        var buy = new BuySMTH();
        this.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        buy.Show();
    }

    private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e) {           
        Initialize();
    }

    private void Tmp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        currentMoney.addMoney(1000);
    }
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Coursage.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Coursage"
    xmlns:model="clr-namespace:Coursage.Logic.Money"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    ContentRendered="Window_ContentRendered"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="545.802">
<Window.Resources>
    <model:Money x:Key="Money" ></model:Money>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Money}}">
    <Menu Panel.ZIndex="-1" Height="25px" Width="Auto" Background="Yellow" Margin="0,0,0,398">
        <MenuItem Header="Info" Background="Green"></MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Buy" Click="MenuItem_Click" Background="Red"></MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Info" Background="Blue"></MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <Label Content="{Binding Path=CurrentMoney}" Name="CurrentMoney" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,23,0,0"/>
    <Label Content="Population: " Name="Population"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,49,0,0"/>
    <Label Content="Current pollution: " Name="CurrentPollution" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,80,0,0"/>
    <Label Content="Number of factories: " Name="Facktories" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,235,0,0"/>
    <Label Content="Pollution of factories: " Name="FactoriesPollution" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,261,0,0"/>
    <Label Content="Number of cars: " Name="Cars" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="250,235,0,0"/>
    <Label Content="Pollution of cars: " x:Name="CarsPollution" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="250,261,0,0"/>
    <Label Content="Start Date: " x:Name="StartDate" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="267,25,0,0"/>
    <Label Content="Day Count: " x:Name="DayCount" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="267,56,0,0"/>
    <Label Content="Date: " x:Name="Date" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="267,80,0,0"/>
    <Button Name="Tmp" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="81,149,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Tmp_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Your best bet here is to find a working example of a simple viewmodel, and very closely imitate that example instead of trying to invent your own way of doing things. When you imitate that example, you may see a lot of things you think you can do differently because you just know they "don't matter". But they do matter. Don't do anything differently. Your code isn't following any working examples you've seen. Follow the examples.

Comment: I would suggest learning MVVM and getting away from writing in code behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement the interface on the property itself. Also, when invoking the PropertyChanged event, you should use a local(scoped) handle to the event to avoid race conditions.

```
public class Money : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    double _currentMoney;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public double CurrentMoney 
    { 
         get => _currentMoney;
         set
         {
             _currentMoney = value;
             OnPropertyChanged();
         }
    }

    public Money() => CurrentMoney = 1000;

    public int addMoney(double count) {
        CurrentMoney += count;
        return 1;
    }       

    public int subMoney(double count) {
        CurrentMoney -= count;
        if (CurrentMoney < 0) { return 100; }
        return 1;
    }

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) 
    {
        var handle = PropertyChanged;
        handle?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

EDIT: To save yourself some typing you can also create a ViewModelBase class to handle the smaller details.

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) 
    {
        var handle = PropertyChanged;
        handle?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public virtual void Dispose() => PropertyChanged = null;
}
```

Then when implementing a viewModel class just inherit from base(but still notify on property changes).

```
public class MyClass : ViewModelBase
{
    string _myField;
    public string MyProperty
    {
        get => _myField;
        set
        {
            _myField = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        } 
    }
}
```

NOTE: The actual bug comes from the [CallerMemberName] attribute and calling the method from within another method. You can either pass in the name of the property as parameter or use the method from with the property itself without having to specify the property name.

Comment: I changed code, can you look at XAML. Still have PropertyChanged NULL

Comment: You are setting 2 way bindings on labels which the user can not edit, you are setting the labels content in xaml and in code, and you need to create a DataContext(viewModel) for your Window or set the Binding to the window and set the path to the property.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the prop name which is modified

`NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentMoney");`

Answer (score 0):

The NotifyPropertyChanged take a propertyName as parameter. Default value is null.

```
private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) {
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

You can use NotifyPropertyChanged("propertyName") if you want to see the changes to "propertyName" on ui.

For yours sample the propertyName is "CurrentMoney"